# Passing double splat arguments as a Hash raises ArgumentError in Ruby 2.7.0+

Tags: ruby

Ruby 2.7.0 introduced [some changes to keyword arguments](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/25/ruby-2-7-0-released/). However, now calling a method which accepts a double splat as a second argument `def test(arg, **opts)` as a Hash `test(:test, { foo: 'bar', bat: 'baz' })` raises an ArgumentError and I cannot understand why.

```
def test(arg, **opts)
  puts arg, opts
end

# Passing options as Hash raises an ArgumentError
test(:foo, { from: true, to: false })
# (irb):1:in `test': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)

# Simply passing as keywords does not raise an error
test(:foo, from: true, to: false)
```

I am specifically running Ruby 3.1.4, but I do not see any changes to how this works since Ruby 2.7.0.

Comment: The main difference between how Ruby 2.7 and 3.x handle keyword arguments and the double splat operator is that Ruby 2.7 only prints a warning, whereas Ruby 3.x raises an exception. This is explained in the release notes you linked and on subsequent linked pages. Ruby 2.7 introduced a new concept and Ruby 3 deprecated old behavior: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/#what-is-deprecated

Comment: In Ruby 3.x you can still pass hashes as keyword arguments, but you have to convert them explicitly via `**`, i.e. `test(:foo, **{ from: true, to: false })`